# How to pass class's self through a flask.Blueprint.route decorator?

Tags: python, decorator, flask

I am writing my website's backend using Flask and Python 2.7, and have run into a bit of a problem. I like to use classes to enclose my functions, it makes things neat for me and helps me keep everything modular. One problem I'm having, though, is that the decorators flask uses for routing doesn't preserve the self variable. I use this for accessing the loadDb method of the class that its in. See below. Anyone have any ideas why this is happening, and know how I could solve this, or even if there is a way to solve this?

```
class Test(object):
    blueprint = Blueprint("Test", __name__)
    def __init__(self, db_host, db_port):
        self.db_host = db_host
        self.db_port = db_port
    def loadDb(self):
        return Connection(self.db_host, self.db_port)
    @blueprint.route("/<var>")
    def testView(var): # adding self here gives me an error
        return render_template("base.html", myvar=self.loadDb().find({"id": var})
```

Comment: I suspect you may want to use pluggable views with MethodView.  It gets kind of ugly because you can't fine multiple routes within a single class.  But you could pass your model class into the view class contrsuctor and then there would be a handle back to your model class for each route.  It's a way to separate the view/model logic.  You could create a higher level class that contains each view so you only have to instantiate once.  But it ultimately still goes back to adding an add_url_rule to link everything back to flask. https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/views/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an error if you add `self` because the method works the same as a function for the decorator, and the flask isn't expecting a function with a first argument `self`.

Let's look at the code of `route` : https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/src/flask/blueprints.py#L52

It calls `self.add_url_rule` (self being the `Blueprint`) with a few arguments, one of those being the function. What you want is to add a rule with the method bound to an instance of `Test`(`self.testView`), not the method itself (`Test.testview`). This is tricky because the decorator is executed at the creation of the class, before any instance ever exist.

The solution I can suggest, asside from avoiding to put your views as methods of a class, is to call yourself `blueprint.add_url_rule` in the contructor of `Test` (i.e., at the first point the instance of `Test` is known.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I wish there were another way around this other than that. Looks like there's not, though, so this'll have to do. Thanks.

Comment: Have a broken link.

Comment: I fixed it, but really it's just a link pointing to the blueprint's add_url_rule method, so nothing special.